# the_excerpt() does not work with has_excerpt()?

Tags: filters, excerpt

I'm trying to shorten the excerpt but it does not work. It shows the full excerpt which I write in the post edit!

I've added this to the functions.php

```
function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 20;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

To show the excerpt I'm using in content.php:

`if(has_excerpt()) { the_excerpt(); } else { the_content(); }`

The above code display full excerpt, not shortened!

Without `has_excerpt()` `if statement` it displays correctly.

Where can be the problem? Any ideas what can cause this?

Comment: where is your  `)` for `if` statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`excerpt_length` [is only applied to generated excerpts](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-includes/formatting.php#L2373)-- excerpts automatically generated from the post body.

To trim your manually created excerpt, [use the same function that trims the generated one](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-includes/formatting.php#L2382)-- [`wp_trim_words`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_words).

```
if(has_excerpt()) { 
  $length = apply_filters('excerpt_length',20);
  echo wp_trim_words(get_the_excerpt(),$length); 
} else { 
  the_content(); 
}
```